# cannot make ffmpeg gem work on windows (ruby)

Tags: ruby, ffmpeg

I installed [ffmpeg](http://github.com/polly/ffmpeg) on my windows machine with no error message using `gem install ffmpeg`. hm so did I actully install ffmpeg-ruby from [here?](http://github.com/gwik/ffmpeg-ruby)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ffmpeg'

video = FFMPEG::InputFormat.new('alligator.mp4')
```

gives me `'NameError: uninitialized constant FFMPEG"`

Does anybody have **working ffmpeg ruby gem under windows** the way it would give a **length of a video file**?

**UPDATE:** I can now see that I installed ffmpeg (not ffmpeg-ruby) but was using code sample from ffmpeg-ruby which did not work, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem like you got the wrong gem.
gem install ffmpeg --> http://gemcutter.org/gems/ffmpeg
gem install ffmpeg-ruby --> http://gemcutter.org/gems/ffmpeg-ruby

My guess would be that the ffmpeg-ruby version won't install on windows (because it can't compile ffmpeg)